# Connection attempt failed in my socket client server program

Tags: python, sockets

I am new at `socket` programming. I am trying to make simple client server program, so I wrote this code:

This is the server program.

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 50007

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr=s.accept()
print('Connected by',addr)
while True:
    data=conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

This is client program:

```
import socket

HOST = '10.87.24.139'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('Hello World')
s.close()
print('received', repr(data))
```

When I run this the client shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James Bond\Desktop\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Where is the problem? Why did this error occur?

Comment: Is that `HOST` value correct?

Comment: If you interrupt the (still running, right?) server program, what line is it on?

Comment: Oh.I find my problem. The host value was not correct.

Comment: My local ip often changing and this error occur...what can i do...??? @DavisHerring

Comment: You can always connect to (and listen on) `localhost`.